# Why am I receiving a nil when passing data from one viewcontroller to another?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass the label text and image of the selected cell to another *ViewController*. I am using `NSDictionary`, but I am receiving a `nil` when I print the `NSDictionary`. Am I instantiating it correctly? Why am I receiving the `nil` value? How do I fix it? Below is the code to my `UICollectionView`.

```
var dicSelected : NSDictionary!
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.item) selected")
    print(arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item])
     self.dicSelected = ["friendname" : arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item], "friendimage" :  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.item]]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("friendaccess", sender: dicSelected)
}

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "friendaccess"){

        let nextViewOBJ = segue.destinationViewController as! FriendProfilePages

        nextViewOBJ.dicData = self.dicSelected;

    }
}
```

Below is the code for the *FriendProfilePages*.

```
var friendname = UILabel()
var friendimage = UIImageView()
var dicData : NSDictionary?

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      //receiving nil here
    print("Dictionary: \(self.dicData)")
}
```

Comment: Could you please log (print) `self.dicSelected` just after setting it in `didSelect` and just before fetching it in `prepareFor`?

Comment: Are you checked it : self.dicSelected = ["friendname" : arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item], "friendimage" :  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.item]] I think it be nil here.

Comment: Also, please make sure you are not performing some sort of double-instantiation - that is, make sure the segue is not already being triggered automatically in the storyboard.

Comment: Here is the `self.dicSelected` http://puu.sh/l1uf1/42c90992be.png. And how will I know if it is being triggered automatically?

Comment: You can put break point into prepare for segue. Make sure before go next screen, data is setted.

Comment: http://puu.sh/l1xEh/96e3032434.png The dicData is nil

Comment: I have gotten the data to transfer over to the the next view controller, but how do I assign the image and label to the ones in the nsdictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on the first line of prepareForSegue and single-step to see what's happening. My guess is that the segue id isn't matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print it from the "viewDidAppear". Probably nothing is "set" to the object before it is fully present in the view hierarchy